# Allocating memory inside a function and returning it back

Tags: c, memory, pointers, allocation, malloc

I want to pass a pointer to my function and allocate the memory to which this pointer points. I've read in other posts that I should pass a double pointer to this function and I did so, but I keep getting  segmentation fault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void allocate(unsigned char** t)
{
    *t=(unsigned char*)malloc(3*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(*t == NULL)
        cout<<"Allcoation failed"<<endl;
    else
        for(int m=0;m<3;m++)
            *(t[m])=0;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char* t;
    allocate(&t); 
    cout<<t[0]<<" "<<t[1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the result is always this:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I don't think that there's anything missing from this code. What could be wrong?

Comment: Step 1: Use a debugger and determine exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: Returning it *back*? As opposed to returning it forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is treading where it shouldn't:

```
*(t[m])=0;
```

Consider the case where m is 2. That's unallocated memory you're writing to. You've done nothing to claim it from the runtime heap.

You may be thinking of something like this:

```
t[0][m]=0;
```

Comment: You're right. writing *(*t+m)=0; or t[0][m]=0; resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line: `*(t[m]) = 0;`. Since you have given `t[m]` precedence, it will look for the `m`-th pointer to `char` and dereference that. What you actually want to do is dereference `t` and find the `char` `m` places after that, or `(*t)[m]`. Making this change causes your code to work perfectly: http://ideone.com/JAWeS2